# Incoming requests: context with custom typed fields

Tags: go, design-patterns, go-http

I'm writing a more or less simple web application using go that provides a rest api. When a request comes in, I want to store the id of the user, which is part of the api token, temporarily inside the requests context. After [reading](https://www.calhoun.io/pitfalls-of-context-values-and-how-to-avoid-or-mitigate-them/) [some](https://blog.golang.org/context) [articles](https://medium.com/@lestrrat/alternative-to-using-context-value-f2efe6bd2788) and the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) I'm still confused how to make sure that the values, that one attaches to the context using `context.WithValue()`, can be used without type assertion, but a struct of sorts instead.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
// RequestContext contains the application-specific information that are carried around in a request.
type RequestContext interface {
    context.Context
    // UserID returns the ID of the user for the current request
    UserID() uuid.UUID
    // SetUserID sets the ID of the currently authenticated user
    SetUserID(id uuid.UUID)
}

type requestContext struct {
    context.Context           // the golang context
    now             time.Time // the time when the request is being processed
    userID          uuid.UUID // an ID identifying the current user
}

func (ctx *requestContext) UserID() uuid.UUID {
    return ctx.userID
}

func (ctx *requestContext) SetUserID(id uuid.UUID) {
    ctx.userID = id
}

func (ctx *requestContext) Now() time.Time {
    return ctx.now
}

// NewRequestContext creates a new RequestContext with the current request information.
func NewRequestContext(now time.Time, r *http.Request) RequestContext {
    return &requestContext{
        Context: r.Context(),
        now:     now,
    }
}

// RequestContextHandler is a middleware that sets up a new RequestContext and attaches it to the current request.
func RequestContextHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        now := time.Now()
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(NewRequestContext(now, r)))
    })
}
```

I would like to know how I can access the `SetUserID()` and `UserID()` functions of the request context inside a handler or if there is an alternative, similar approach.

Comment: Context is a great way to manage cancellation and a terrible way to pass data. You'd be better off just making `RequestContext` a regular struct (not trying to make it `context.Context`-compatible) and making your handlers methods on that struct. That way you can fill in whatever fields you want, type-safe, and then call the handler method, which can access those fields on its receiver.

Comment: Very well put. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

To use what you built, you have to use type assertions:

```
rctx:=request.Context().(RequestContext)
```

This will break if you have a middleware that wraps the context the same way you did.

An alternative is using the base context, and adding helpers with a private key to access values:

```
type reqKey int

const key reqKey=iota

type RequestData struct {
   UserID uuid.UUID
   Now time.Time
}

func ContextWithRequest(ctx context.Context,req requestData) context.Context {
  return context.WithValue(ctx,key,req)
}

func GetRequest(ctx context) RequestData {
  x:=ctx.Value(key)
  if x!=nil {
     return x.(RequestData)
  }
  return RequestData{}
}
```

Of course, if you want to change the `RequestData`, you need to add a pointer to the context.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using in my application now. I use simple settters and getters to retrieve values from the context.

```
import (
    "context"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

const userIdContextKey = "user_id" // type is uuid

func addUserIdToContext(ctx context.Context, user uuid.UUID) context.Context {
    return context.WithValue(ctx, UserIdContextKey, user)
}

func userIDFromContext(ctx context.Context) uuid.UUID {
    return ctx.Value(UserIdContextKey).(uuid.UUID)
}
```

Then in a middleware, where I've retrieved the userId, I add the value to the context, by passing the context and user id to the `addUserIdToContext()` function.

```
ctx := addUserIdToContext(r.Context(), userId)
```

When I want to retrieve the user from the context, I just have to call `userIDFromContext(ctx)` and pass it the requests context.

```
func CreateResource(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    createdBy := userIDFromContext(r.Context())
    // do something with createdBy
}
```

I'm aware that this isn't the most elegant or even type safe solution, but hey, for what I'm trying to build it works just fine.